# Are Warehouse 13 characters Pete Lattimer and Steve Jinks Alphas?

Tags: warehouse-13, sy-fy, powers, crossovers, alphas

In the SyFy TV show Warehouse 13 characters Pete Lattimer and Steve Jinks both have supernatural-abilities that can't be explained by science, nor by the use of any artifact (the show's premise).

Alphas is another TV show from SyFy that has been established to be in the same universe as Warehouse 13 (in Alphas' episode 5 of season 1, "Never Let Me Go", featuring guest star Lindsay Wagner as Dr. Vanessa Calder, a character from Warehouse 13). This show focuses on people with supernatural-abilities, which are caused by genetic mutations.

Pete Lattimer has limited precognitive abilities in the form of "vibes". They are limited to feelings, positive or negative. Steve Jinks can sense with definite accuracy when someone is lying.

**So are Pete Lattimer and Steve Jinks Alphas?**

Comment: I think eureka has several too.

Comment: @Chad Really? Who? I don't recall anyone with Alpha-like abilities in Eureka.

Comment: I think most of the town.  The abilities may not be alpha like but definitely a place for highly intelligent and some niche abilities that are super-normal.  And they are all in the same universe with all the crossovers etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, by the definitions of the show Alphas, their abilities are very minor and would not be considered on the same scale as the other Alphas on the show. Lattimer and Jinks abilities while seeming extraordinary could be explained with an understanding of human psychology ([for the detection of lies](http://www.clarkfreshman.com/)) and a well-ordered and trained observation skill (to explain Lattimer's [detection of "vibes"](http://ideas.time.com/2012/05/02/how-to-incease-your-powers-of-observation/)) when they are confronting new experiences.

Most of the Alpha powers are quite considerable:

- Superhuman strength - Bill
- Electromagnetic visualization and manipulation - Gary
- Psychic Domination - Nina
- Superhuman sensory abilities - Rachael
- Kinesthetic Mastery - Cameron

These abilities are far beyond anything a normal human could even attempt or learn. This is the nature of Alpha powers, they can't be learned by normal humans, they are an evolution of human ability.

Perhaps Lattimer and Jinks could take their show on the road and call it Betas...

Comment: I agree their abilities are quite minor compared to those of the characters from Alphas. But they are still beyond that of normal humans. So Betas sounds appropriate :P

Comment: @PaulT. - plenty of people have enhanced danger sense.

Comment: @DVK indeed, however Pete's ability seem to be a bit more than just danger sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Betas is inappropriate because the degree of the powers displayed on the show varies greatly. Just look at Kat, her power was simply to LEARN.

Answer (score 0):

They are alphas. The two worlds exist in the same reality and since their abilities are natural traits it is safe to assume that they are alphas. The same could be true of Leena's ability to read auras and Claudia's ability to connect with artifacts (they both could be detecting various types of energy.